# What are the tools required to develop iOS applications?

Tags: iphone, ios, development

What are the tools (hardware/software) required to develop iOS applications? Because I want to learn iPhone application development.

Comment: [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) is your best starting point.

Comment: You're welcome, Jyoti. At the time of my comment, your post was flagged for possible deletion and I wanted to give you a nugget of information before it went away. Fortunately, your post was not deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a Mac (any current model will do) and Xcode which can be downloaded from the Mac App Store. It comes with all the tools necessary, including a Simulator. It nevertheless is recommended to test apps on the hardware (aka an iPhone) as well.

Additional details can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode).

Comment: He also needs Mac hardware...

Comment: Could probably link to this: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ide/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If Xcode is too complex, you might consider something such as [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com). With Xojo you can make native iOS apps (and more) using easy drag and drop and Visual Basic-like coding.